# How to create a vector of a type of variable?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

So I have a template function (? not sure it's called that. Starts with 'template' and is a function) vector which I want to hold some data. The problem is – the data may consist of ints, may consist of floats, may consist of other vectors – I only have an iterator pointing at a variable of that type. Can I create a vector for that type? Something like 
"std::vector" or like that?

UPD.

```
template<class InputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
void partial_sort (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred){
    std::vector<????> to_sort;
```

I need the vector 'to_sort' to be able to hold the data that the vector being sorted holds, but all I have are iterators pointing at the first and last elements.

Comment: The std::vector does not really help. Through the template parameter the vector can be of ONE type, e.g. int. Another possibility is creating a list of void* and cast them to the real type but thats ugly. Maybe you should consider storing a custom data type that can handle the requirement of your problem domain

Comment: Could you add your function code?

Comment: Could you show the signature of your template function, i.e. the `template` part and a list of all parameters, up to the opening bracket? If you take iterator of unknown type as a parameter, please show that iterator as well.

Comment: Even if you say "its ugly", `void *` is better off left unmentioned.

Comment: Some code would be helpful. You can get the type of the values your iterator points to by using `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type`. Hence you can define your vector by `std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> vec;`, with `It` being the type of your iterator.

Comment: @anhoppe I don't think OP wants to mix items of different type in the same vector; I think he does not know the syntax for creating a vector of a type captured by the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type> to_sort(first, last);
// to_sort will be having all values between [first, last)
```

or

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type _value_type;
std::vector<_value_type> to_sort(first, last);
// to_sort will be having all values between [first, last)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class It>
void myFunction (It b, It e) {
   auto vec = std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> { b, e };
   // now vec is filled with copies of the values between b and e
}
```

Comment: Why you used `auto` instead of `std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> vec{ b, e }`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat compiler automatically deduces the return type.

Comment: @mnciitbhu Please look at my code again. He used `auto var = T(params);` instead of more obivous `T var(params);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry for that, I misunderstood. +1 for your question.

Answer (score 1):

With c++14 you can use

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>::type ValueType;
std::vector<ValueType> vec;
```

Comment: Also from C++ 14 you can use `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>` instead of `std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>::type`